# format HTML5 date picker UI for android

Tags: html

is there any way to show the date picker in the following way in android using HTML5,

[image: html5 display week]

i am using HTML5 date to show the datepicker(showing like calendar) but i want to show the simpler way.

```
<input tye="date">
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally every browser implements their own calendar differently. The best way is to use any external library (like jQuery UI Date-picker) and customize it according to your need !